# Action Bar Title Hidden

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

When selecting a menu item (shown in the screenshot), the text populates the action bar title. The title however is being hidden from the left and right side, and I'm struggling to display more of the title than what is currently showing. The menu item selected was "Equality" where the "u" displays.

[image: Screen Shot]

For help, here's my action_bar.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:gravity="left|center"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:text="Action Bar Title"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

options_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/search"
      android:title="@string/search_title"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
      android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
      android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
<!-- android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom" -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_bookmark"
    android:title="Bookmarks"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_twitter"
    android:title="Twitter"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"/>
```

Controller.java

```
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(mActivity,                  /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            mActivity.getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            mActivity.invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            mActivity.getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            mActivity.invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
```

Activity.java

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    menu.findItem(R.id.action_bookmark).setIcon(
            new IconDrawable(this, IconValue.fa_bookmark_o)
                    .colorRes(R.color.aha_white)
                    .actionBarSize());
    menu.findItem(R.id.menu_twitter).setIcon(
            new IconDrawable(this, IconValue.fa_twitter)
                    .colorRes(R.color.aha_white)
                    .actionBarSize());
```

Thanks for anyone's help!

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but even if you could fit the title, it would look bad. You should just not have one there and if absolutely critical find another way to convey that text.

Comment: I don't disagree with you @WillEvers.

Comment: in that case, I am sure you know this but you can just remove the title tags in the xml and the setTitle lines in your Controller class   OR set it to null.

Comment: @WillEvers I'm honestly new to Android, as this project was passed to me. I definitely appreciate the good advice. Still have to display this title text at the top somehow.